# Retrieve duplicate documents from mongo collection matching certain conditions

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is a mongo collection named customerFinance containing a list of 4 documents

```
[
    {"VIN": 100,
    "CUSTOMER_TYPE": "1-PRIMARY BORROWER",
    "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME":"MATT",
    "DEAL_TYPE":"LEASE",
    "CONTRACT_START_DATE": "04/30/2021"},
    {"VIN": 101,
    "CUSTOMER_TYPE": "1-PRIMARY BORROWER",
    "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME":"JOHN",
    "DEAL_TYPE":"LEASE",
    "CONTRACT_START_DATE": "04/30/2021"},
    {"VIN": 101,
    "CUSTOMER_TYPE": "6-CO BORROWER",
    "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME":"SUSAN",
    "DEAL_TYPE":"LEASE",
    "CONTRACT_START_DATE": "04/30/2022"},
    {"VIN": 100,
    "CUSTOMER_TYPE": "1-PRIMARY BORROWER",
    "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME":"MATT",
    "DEAL_TYPE":"RETAIL",
    "CONTRACT_START_DATE": "04/30/2022"}
]
```

My goal is to retrieve only the first and fourth document from this collection as you can see they both have the following fields same - VIN, CUSTOMER_TYPE, CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME

With the below piece of Java code, I am able to filter those VINs whose count is greater than 1

```
GroupOperation groupByVin = group("VIN").count().as("VIN_COUNT");
MatchOperation filterVins = match(new Criteria("VIN_COUNT").gt(1));
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(groupByVin, filterVins);
AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "customerFinance", Document.class);
return result.getMappedResults();
```

And I get the below result

```
   [{"_id": 100,
    "VIN_COUNT": 2}]

But I want my result to look like the below format

[
{"VIN": 100,
 "CUSTOMER_TYPE": "1-PRIMARY BORROWER",
 "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME":"MATT",
 "DEAL_TYPE":"LEASE",
 "CONTRACT_START_DATE": "04/30/2021"
},
{"VIN": 100,
 "CUSTOMER_TYPE": "1-PRIMARY BORROWER",
 "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME":"MATT",
 "DEAL_TYPE":"RETAIL",
 "CONTRACT_START_DATE": "04/30/2022"
}
]
```

Could you please help me understand on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mongoDB syntax you can do it like this:

Since you want the original documents in your results, you need to keep them during the `$group` step. One way of doing it, is `$push: "$ROOT"`.
The last two steps are just to format it as you wanted, since they are grouped together.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$VIN", data: {$push: "$$ROOT"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/64BUU5BvMZF)

Comment: Could you please help me understand on how can I do this using Java code?